# Google Apps Script copies spreadsheet every time I run the script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script that executes a function every time I open the spreadsheet the script is linked to.

But now every time I run the function, a copy of the spreadsheet is created and that definitely shouldn't happen.

I'm not sure if it might have to do with the triggers or type of deployment I set. I put a screenshot of the trigger here.

[image: This is the trigger I set]

As the type of deployment I put web app.

The code in the script is pretty simple because I didn't want to go forward yet when the error is still happening. It looks like this:

```js
function mediaplan() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s_week = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Quick view - Week");
  var s_month = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Quick view - Month");
  var test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");

  var currentWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "w"); 
  console.log(currentWeek);

}
```

It would be great if someone could tell me what I did wrong or if it's an error by Google.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that the complete script? I tested it and it does not create duplicates on my end.

Comment: There's nothing that code that will create a copy of the spreadsheet so... what other functions &/or triggers do you have running? What do you mean by "As the type of deployment I put web app." - that doesn't make sense in the context of this function.